# How to delete items within .pbl files removed from SVN using PowerBuilerIDE with PushOK(SVN)?

Tags: powerbuilder

My team and I work with PowerBuilder and use PushOK for the implementation of Tortoise SVN.

When one of the teammembers deletes some items within the .pbl-files from sourcecontrol every other member has to search for every item manually to delete them.

At the moment I can see deleted items in the PowerBuilder IDE with 'Add to source control' and delete them manually.

Can anyone tell me how to remove those items fast(automatically) from the PowerBuilder IDE?

Comment: sorry, i mean items within the .pbl! Thanks!

Comment: I recall researching this when I was using PowerBuilder with StarTeam. I remember reading that PowerBuilder would never automatically delete items from pbls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the various source control tools I've used with PB (your described setup, TFS, SourceSafe) the removal of local copies of objects is always a manual process.  Normally something like:

- Disconnect from source control.
- Delete obejcts in your local pbls.
- Reconnect to source control.
- Get latest version on application.
- Full rebuild of application.

The same goes for when objects are moved between pbls.  The only way I see of getting around this is to get a new set of pbls (from the dev who removed the objects or perhaps source control) after the objects are removed (and then performing a 'get latest version' on them).

Changes of this type should always be communicated to the entire team to help insure libraries are consistent within the group.

Comment: To expand on what Matt said, some teams solve this problem by getting fresh copies of the PBLs from a build server.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to find objects that aren't in source control is to right-click the target and select Add to Source Control. Also, if you sort the object list in the library manager on Version the objects that aren't in source control will appear together at the top (or bottom).